# How to view file extension in macOS 'Save As' dialogue box in web browser

Tags: macos, google-chrome, finder, file-extension, save-as

In macOS (Monterey), when I save files in a web browser (ex. Chrome or Safari), I cannot view the file extension in the save dialogue box. This means I must download the file before finding out the file type, which loses time and can be a security risk. Below is a screenshot (after saving the file, Finder shows it has a .png extension). There is no 'Show file extension' check box at the bottom as is sometimes the case. **When saving a file in a web browser, how to view the file extension in the 'Save As' dialogue box?**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON6AJ.png)

Comment: Is in *Finder > Preferences > Advanced* is checked "Show all filename extensions"?

Comment: @harrymc I have that checked, but the file extension still doesn't display in the browser download box (ex. when downloading an email attachment)

Comment: Is it the same in for example Firefox?

Comment: It's the same in Safari (I don't use Firefox)

Comment: I see this behavior in Mojave, too, across all browsers. Typical MacOS bug/oversight/lack of QA. The OS is riddled with them at this point.
It's not a security issue for me, but is an annoyance, especially with images.